# Running an express server from WSL (UNC paths are not supported)

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I’m trying to run an express server from a WSL terminal in Visual Studio Code.

However, whenever, I run the command `npm run dev`, I get the following error:

```
'\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\simao\legalize-backend'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

I assume it has something to do with the path from windows to the folder in the WSL directory.

Which one is the right path format or what should I do to make this one valid?

Searching, I found that you can:

> You can solve this problem (UNC Paths not supported) by mapping a normal drive letter to the path that has the UNC path.

But how do I map a normal drive letter to the path?

Comment: I think those who encounter this issue should take a look at https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6280 and referenced issues and PRs. I haven't figured how to solve this yet, though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because whatever tool you are using is trying to run commands via `cmd.exe` and `cmd.exe` does not understand [UNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) paths (those starting with `\\...` rather than a drive letter). Mapping a UNC path to a drive will convert it to a drive letter path.

To map a WSL path to a Windows drive, run `cmd.exe` (Command Line) and type the following command:

```
net use X: \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\simao
```

Where `X:` is the drive that will be created (you'll see it as network drive in e.g. *My Computer*) and `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\simao` is the WSL path to the root of that drive. `wsl$` is a special hostname that tells Windows to connect to WSL, `Ubuntu` is a distribution name under WSL, and then finally `\home\simao` is a path to a directory in the `Ubuntu` distribution that should be mapped.

Comment: error: `System error 67 has occurred. The network name cannot be found.`

Comment: @Sheldeeb This error occurs when your Windows network configuration is wrong or system policy prohibits mapping drives. My solution relies on that.

Comment: what exactly wrong in those configurations/ or what should I check for?

Answer (score 8):

I confronted the same situation yesterday. I assume maybe it was something wrong with my npm. Then I checked the npm path with `which npm`, and I found that my npm was mounted `D:\nodejs\npm` in Windows (exactly `/mnt/d/nodejs/npm` in screen).

I guess WSL uses CMD.exe to start npm from Windows described in `CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.`

So maybe I can just install a new npm in WSL to solve this. Node Version Manager (nvm), is the most popular way to install multiple versions of Node.js. And each version of nodejs has its own version of npm. Just follow the link below.

[Install nvm, node.js, and npm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dev-environment/javascript/nodejs-on-wsl)

Plus, if you have `Permission denied`, use `npm uninstall xxx` to remove your dependencies you've installed, and install your dependencies again.

Answer (score 7):

The error I had was because my Ubuntu WSL was trying to use npm install on my Windows system. To validate it, execute the command:

```
which npm # output = /mnt/c/ubuntu/...
```

The expected output should be something like /usr/local7....

Solution: install npm directly on Ubuntu. You can do it using nvm:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | tried
source ~/.bashrc
```

When it is ready, you can run npm without problems.

Comment: Installing npm in WSL with `sudo apt install npm` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install it through NVM :

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/master/install.sh | bash

source ~/.bashrc

nvm install --lts
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I had this error too. After making sure Node.js and npm were installed on Ubuntu I was still getting the error when I ran `npm run dev` .

I realised I was in a virtual environment, so ran `npm run dev` outside of the virtual environment, in another terminal window and it finally worked.

Answer (score -1):

As it being mentioned, .nvm or npm is not added to PATH in .bashrc or .zshrc, so if do so and run `source .zshrc` it should work

Answer (score -2):

You are using Node.js' npm on Windows.
Try to install it in Windows Subsystem for Linux directly.

Then when you hit `npm run`, it firstly go to the Windows npm.

Try to remove npm from Windows and just install it in WSL Ubuntu or whatever.
This will force WSL to use its npm installation.

I tried this solution, and it worked correctly for me.

I am using WSL [Debian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) in [Windows 11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_11).

Comment: This seems to me to be exactly the same problem and solution that is covered (in more detail) in two existing answers already on this question from [Swift King](/a/75407212) and [juan rodriguez](/a/76876425).  If you feel you have a different solution, please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/78053892/edit) your answer to include more detail, including what sets it apart from the existing answers. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer has been deleted by a Moderator, and you would like to have it considered for undeletion after your edits, you can Flag the answer and request that a Moderator re-review it.