# Not able to use a npm start from WSL ( UNC paths are not supported )

Tags: reactjs, windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using WSL 2 on windows 11. When I am trying to use the termainl to create a react project it is giving me this error.

```
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\home\nisnym\t\learn'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

and here is the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jXJy.png)

I also went through this already existing question, but it is not working for me. [Question Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74000168/running-a-express-server-from-wsl-unc-paths-are-not-supported/75033988#75033988)

If possible please help me fix this.

To be able to run and create react js apps.

–
node and npm install, I already did both installs [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2gaw.png)

Comment: It seems you somehow misconfigured npm to be run in Windows and not Linux

Comment: Make sure you installed nodejs/npm _in WSL_.

Comment: already installed npm in wsl

Comment: @nisnym What does `which npm` give you?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I am not able to understand. If you are asking for npm version then it is 9.1.2

Comment: @nisnym No, I'm trying to determine if `npm` might actually be running from Windows.  I commonly see situations where the Windows version of `npm` is overriding the Linux/WSL version, and I'm suspecting that *might* be the case here.  If you run the command `which npm` from inside WSL, what does it return (if anything)?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks. It returns /home/nisnym/.nvm/versions/node/v18.13.0/bin/npm

Comment: @nisnym Thanks - Definitely running from WSL (not Windows).  I'm going to assume that the accepted answer is correct and that there's some bug in the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their latest version seems broken.
Even `npx -y create-react-app@next` does not seem to work with WSL2,

Try with 5.0.0:

```bash
npx -y create-react-app@5.0.0 testapp
```

Comment: thanks a lot. not sure how but somehow it made it work.

Comment: @nisnym, glad I could help. There's likely a bug in the latest versions of the "create-react-app" module. Versions 4.0.0 and 5.0.0  work fine.
If you're happy with the answer, don't forget to mark it as answered if you can.