# WSL2 VSCode Terminal Errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am running WSL2 Ubuntu 22.04 on Windows 10 and receiving the following message within the VSCode integrated terminal. I have zero configured profiles within any of my `settings.json` files.

*VSCode is connected*

[image]

*integrated terminal message*

```
'\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu-22.04\home\jammy\test\tutorial'
CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory.
UNC paths are not supported.  Defaulting to Windows directory.
```

*These are listed as my available terminal profiles.*

[image]

Comment: google search query with a bunch of fixed bugs: github vscode issues wsl "CMD.EXE was started with the above path as the current directory" "UNC paths are not supported". possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74000168/11107541. I'd suggest you raise an issue ticket of your own using the `Help > Report Issue` feature of VS Code. If you do, please ping me with a link to your issue ticket.